# Swift firebase push notification not working with zero error?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to create push notification I successfully generate APNs auth key and I upload it to firebase and everything working in there. I add some functions and delegate in my app delegate which are these:

```
   let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()//Yeni
    notificationCenter.delegate = self//yeni

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as? MessagingDelegate
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()



// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the FCM registration token.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

And these codes extensions:

```
// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.


   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }


}


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

I can't find any problem in that point. I create new push notification in firebase and I can't reach it from my device. I already read docs again and again but I can't find any problem in my code. Why is this happen? Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added PushNotifications Capability in your App?

Is your Firebase Messaging correctly configured?

Did you upload the correct APNs Certificate?